# All devices Unsupported with New android app update

Tags: android, apk, developer-console

I'm having to upload an update to an existing app but doing this, the update is showing 0 devices supported.

Manifest On Permissions/Features:

```
<!-- Required for the Urban Airship library -->
<permission
    android:name="com.sycuan.permission.UA_DATA"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sycuan.permission.UA_DATA" />

<!-- Required for Push -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- Required for Geofence -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.locations.gps" />
```

I can't figure this out.  It's being built with following sdks:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
```

Is there a way to see the difference in builds on developer console to see what feature caused this from the one that worked?

Comment: Did you sign it with the same certificate as the original app, is the update version number greater than the version of the old app?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have changed the targetSdkVersion to 23 from an earlier api. I seem to remember api 23 was when the new on the fly rather than at install permission protocol was introduced.

Comment: Yes, it was api 23, see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html